# Rhino and Javascript 1.8?

Tags: javascript, rhino

Is it possible to have Rhino use a newer implementation of JS than 1.7?

Do we have to wait for mozilla to do this, or is there a community project that has taken the lead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about JavaScript 1.8, but I know they are actively working on ECMAScript 5 support. The [RingoJS project](http://ringojs.org/wiki/) (formerly Helma NG) has a customized branch that implements some of the new features from 1.8 and ECMAScript 5. For example, it supports function expressions (`f = function(x) 2 * x;` instead of `f = function(x) { return 2 * x; }`), `JSON.stringify/parse`, and `Object.create/seal/freeze`.

I'm sure Mozilla would welcome any help moving to 1.8, but I'm not aware of any projects right now that are working on that.

Answer (score 1):

Umm ... Rhino doesn't *use* an implementation of Javascript, it *is* an implementation of Javascript.

Comment: That should better have been a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: I disagree.  The **answer** to the question is "no", and that's what I wrote :-)

Answer (score 0):

[SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) runs JS 1.8, but is implemented in C instead of Java, not sure if it makes a difference for you.